# Best practice: Want to partially pull commits with git

Tags: git, version-control

I'm in charge of a department webserver, that has a lot of small, one-page modules (most of them just display a dynamically-generated reports), and some larger ones that consist of 5-20 different html pages. Almost all of this is done in perl, with a few java helpers here and there.

There are only two servers: the production one, and my dev server, and it's very unlikely a third will ever be added. But the department wants quick turnaround times, so when someone comes in my office asking "Can you produce a report how many foos were in which bar over the last 12 months", they want this web page in production after an hour or 2. So we don't have a complicated build-and-deploy process - generally, i build the page on my dev server, test it, `git commit` and `git push` it on the dev server, and `git pull` it on production. This works well for everybody.

Now my problem is, when i work on a bigger project, i want to use git for my changes, even if i don't want to make them live yet. And at the same time, i want to be able to interrupt the bigger project, do a small task, commit-push-pull the small task, and omit the big-project file from the pull. For example,

```
git commit -m "First attempt, not finished yet" bigproject/file1 bigproject/file2
```

then

```
git commit -m "reversed foo and bar" smallfix/file3
```

and then pull `file3`, but not `file1` and `file2` to production.

As far as i understand git, tags won't help me, because i can only pull "everything that precedes the tag", and branching doesn't help much either, because i'd have to commit everything, change the branch, do some work there, commit everything again, then change back - and i'd need to always know which branch i want to work on before touching some code.

So right now, i'm using two sandboxes on the same machine and use one for short-term stuff, another for long-term things, but i doubt this is the best way to solve the problem. So how do i do this "correctly" / with git?

Comment: "i'd have to commit everything" nope.  `add --patch` and `checkout --merge` are friends, you can drop-ship selected changes from your worktree to any branch, retain the rest for later/elsewhere, at any time that makes sense to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like branching is exactly what you want. Check out Git Flow (http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

What it sounds like you're describing is wanting to do long-running development which doesn't get deployed until it is ready, but not block the release of further code because of those changes. Git Flow (and other branching strategies) solves this by having a feature branches which get merged back into the main development branch, and then a further master branch for releases. It's worth reading the article for the merits of each one, but a short walkthrough would be:

1. I create a feature branch for `big-project-x`, which is branched from develop.
2. I work on that project for a while, committing as I go.
3. Bob comes in an says "I need report Y", so I create a `report-y` feature branch, which is taken from develop and doesn't include any `big-project-x` changes.
4. I complete `report-y`, merge back into `develop` and then push those changes to the server.
5. To make my life easier I merge develop into `big-project-x` so it's got the latest changes.
6. Some time later I finish `big-project-x`, merge that into `develop` and then push to the server.
7. Celebrate!

To address some of the downsides you mention:

1. Git commits are cheap, so if you're switching to working on something else then it's a good idea to commit anyway.
2. If you've done a load of changes and then realise you're on the wrong branch, you may be able to just `git checkout branchname` and then commit, but if there are conflicts you can just use `git stash`, then `git checkout branchname` followed by `git stash apply`. Stash is a great way to store changes for a short time while you jump around.

It does take a little bit of rigour to get into the habit of branching often, but once you get used to it you really get to see the power of Git and its lightweight branching model. Obviously you need to put some effort into making sure long-running branches don't go stale (merge often from develop), but that's the simplest way I can suggest for managing development of fast- and slow-paced items on the same codebase.

Answer (score 1):

An other approach would be having two branches - say, master for the production and develop for development purposes. You do all your work on the develop branch, and when you want something in production, you use [cherry picking](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html) to pick the commits that contain the changes you want.

In the particular case you described in the question, if we call the first commit A and the second commit B, both of those would be done in the develop branch. Then, when you wanted to get B to production:

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick B
git push
```

Then proceed with your workflow as before, making sure that the production server is on the master branch.

Answer (score 0):

@Spikeheap's answer helped me to realize i don't have to clean up before switching branches, which means branches are exactly what i need.

To sum it up, here's my workflow, along with neccesary git commands, in case someone needs a similar setup:

### Commands to use:

- Before each commit, to see which branch i'm on so i don't commit to the wrong one

  `git branch`
- Determine which files have changed:

  `git status`
- Decide some changes should go into a different branch than the one i'm on. This can be done after the changes:

  `git checkout <branch>`     if the branch already exists

  `git checkout master && git checkout -b <branch>`       if it's a new one

  `git commit`
- If `git checkout <branch>` gives me a conflict:

  `git stash`

  `git checkout <branch>`

  `git stash apply`
- Back out if i have commited to the wrong branch (but not pushed yet):

  `git reset --hard HEAD~1`
- Push the current branch:

  `git push -u origin <branch>`
- Merge a branch into master, when i'm finished with a bigger patch:

  `git checkout master`

  `git merge <branch>`
- When i realize i created a new branch off some other development branch instead of master, before committing stuff to it:

  `git checkout master`

  `git branch -d <branch>`

  `git checkout -b <branch>`
- When a quick fix is requested that i want to test on the dev server first:

  on the dev server:

  `git checkout master`

  `<edit files, test>`

  `git commit -m <hotfix desc> <changed filenames>`

  `git push`

  `git checkout <the branch i was working on before>`

  `git merge master`

  on the prod server:

  `git pull`
- When i implement some low-risk change on the prod server directly:

  on the prod server:

  `git commit -m <hotfix desc> <changed filenames>`

  `git push`

  on the dev server:

  `git checkout master`

  `git pull`

  `git checkout <the branch i was working on before>`

  `git merge master`

### Notes:

- Wherever this says

  `git commit <filenames>`

  you can also use

  `git add filename1`

  `git add filename2`

  `git commit`
- As long as no file gets changed in different branches at the same time, i can hop between branches (`git checkout <branch>`) without having to commit or clean up.